# How to use modal windows with ZK and spring?

Tags: zk

I'm upgrading ZK and I have encountered some problems with the creation of modal windows. Because they are created in another thread there's no **hibernate and springsecurity sessions**. How do I call window components on my application without losing servlet variables context?

For instance, the application creates a window with user's preference but when I click save it raises a no hibernate session error.

All over the entire project there are `.zul` files with a `window` component which are called in a composer through a click event:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit"?>
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
<?link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/images/favicon.ico"?>

<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul"
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd">
    <window title="Projetos" apply="common.PreferencesComposer"
            maximizable="true" minimizable="true" closable="true" maximized="true"
            mode="overlapped" border="normal" height="100%" width="100%"
            style="opacity:0.94;">
            [hidden for brevity]
    </window>
</zk>
```

Composer onClick method:

```
Window win = (Window) Executions.createComponents("/common/preferences.zul", null, args);
win.doModal();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ...they are created in another thread...

If you create the modal window in an onClick listenr in a ZK composer, then it should be in a servlet thread.

Unless you enable [Event Threads](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Patterns/Event%20Threads) which is already deprecated.
I strongly recommended you to disable event thread, because it violate the Java Servlet Specification and make you hard to integrate with other frameworks like Spring.

Remember to read the [Event Threads](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Patterns/Event%20Threads) to update the code related to some components  e.g. modal window or message box.

#### How do I use window components on my application with Spring?

The question is unclear. What specific usage do you mean?
You can put a varialbe resolver in a composer to wire a spring bean into the composer and use the bean. Please refer to

- http://books.zkoss.org/zkessentials-book/master/spring_integration/wire_spring_beans.html
- https://github.com/zkoss/zkessentials/blob/zk-spring/src/main/java/org/zkoss/essentials/chapter3/mvvm/ProfileViewModel.java

Notice the example only works with spring 4.3 or before.

Answer (score 0):

1. In you are using MVC architecture. In ZK , the MVVM architecture is considered more preferable
2. Your question is more related to how to integrate with the Spring Framework and get a Hibernate Session

To integrate with Spring, you can use the @VariableResolver annotation(DelegatingVariableResolver.class )
and @WireVariable
then you can inject any bean including  hibernate Session
Example:

```
@VariableResolver annotation(DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
    class МyVM {
     @WireVariable
      Session hibernateSesion;
   //....... your code...
    
      @Command
      public void save(){
        hibernateSesion.save(obj)
      }
    }
```

http://books.zkoss.org/zkessentials-book/master/spring_integration/index.html